# Limit of $\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$

Tags: limits

I would like some help solving this problem.

> Limit of $\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$ as $x$ approaches infinity.

First I let $Y = \lim\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$
Then, I took the natural log of both sides.

$$\ln Y = \lim \ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$$
$$\ln Y = \lim x\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)$$

I used L'Hopital's rule. A slightly different way than WolframAlpha, but I arrived at the same answer:

> **Answer:**
> $$\log\left(\frac1x + 1\right) - \frac1{\left(\frac1x + 1\right)x}$$

Now, when I take the limit as $x$ approaches infinity, I get this:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\log\left(\frac1\infty + 1\right) - \frac1{\left(\frac1\infty + 1\right)\cdot\infty}
 & = & \log(1) - \frac1\infty \\
 & = & \log(1) - 0 \\ 
 & = & \log(1) = 0
\end{eqnarray*}$$

$$\ln y = 0$$

$$e^{\ln y} = e^0$$

$$y = 1$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You should have got $\lim_{x \to \infty} x \ln(1+ \frac{1}{x}) = 1$, which would give $\ln Y = 1$ from which you would get $Y = e$.

Comment: I think I see my problem. I used Lhopital's rule wrong. Instead of taking the derivative of f and g separately I did it as one.

Comment: @QuaxtonHale Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure that you applied L'Hôpital's rule correctly? While it is true that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[ \log\left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)x}\right]=0
$$
are you sure that this is actually $\log(Y)$? Because then (as you show) $Y$ would be $1$ which is false.

Here's my solution:
$$
\log(Y)=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log(1+\tfrac{1}{x})}{\tfrac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{1+x}}{1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1+x}=1.
$$
Thus $Y=e^1=e$.

Comment: I just realized! In fact, I commented on the first post saying that. Thanks though!

Comment: just a small point, if you take log on both sides you get $$\log(Y)=\log\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x \right)$$ and now you need an arguement why you can change the log and the limit (the continuous), and you need that the log is injective else you can't apply it

Comment: @Dominic Michaelis: Yes, you're correct. But the OP already did this "trick", so I assumed he already justified the interchanging. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Evidently, Stefan define the logarithm function as $\log(Y)\equiv \int_1^Y \frac1t\,dt$, which is a differentiable, ,monotonically increasing, unbounded function for $Y>0$.  Then, Stefan defined a number $e>1$ such that $\log(e)=1$.  Such a number exists as guaranteed by the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of derivative,

$$1=\frac{1}{(1)}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(1+h)-\ln(1)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(1+h)}{h}$$

So $$\lim_{h\to0}(1+h)^\frac{1}{h}=e$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x=e$$

Answer (score 0):

> I thought it might be interesting to present an approach that relies on a different characterization of the exponential function $\exp(t)$.  Herein, we shall define $f(t)=\exp(t)$ as the unique solution to the differential equation $f'(t)=f(t)$ subject to the initial condition $f(0)=1$.  To that end, we now proceed.

---

In the analysis that ensues, we appeal to Bernoulli's Inequality

$$(1+x)^r\ge 1+rx\tag1$$

for every real number $r\ge 1$ and real number $x\ge -1$.

---

Let $f(t)$ be defined by the limit

$$f(t)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac tx\right)^x\tag2$$

Note that $f(0)=1$.  We will show next that $f'(t)=f(t)$, which is one of the defining characterizations for $\exp(t)$.

---

The derivative of $f(t)$ is given by the limit quotient

$$\begin{align}
f'(t)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac {t+h}x\right)^x-\left(1+\frac tx\right)^x\right)\\\\
&=f(t)\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac {h}{x+t}\right)^x-1\right)\right)\tag2
\end{align}$$

We fix $t$ and choose $x$ so large that $\frac{h}{t+x}\ge -1$.  Then, applying  Bernoulli's Inequality in $(1)$ reveals that

$$1+\frac{hx}{x+t}\le \left(1+\frac {h}{x+t}\right)^x\le  \frac1{1-\frac{h}{x+t}}\tag3$$

Subtracting $1$ from $(3)$ and letting $x\to \infty$, we find that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac {h}{x+t}\right)^x-1\right)=h$, whence dividing by $h$ and letting $h\to 0$ yields the coveted result

$$f'(t)=f(t)\tag4$$

---

We define the unique solution to $(4)$ coupled with $f(0)=1$ as the function $\exp(t)$.  Hence, $\exp(1)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$.  We denote $e$ as the number $\exp(1)$.  That is, $e\equiv \exp(1)$.

One can show that the function $\exp(t)$ as characterized herein is identical to other characterizations [See Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_the_characterizations).

Comment: @quaxtonHale Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)